# get hidden elements from a set of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a filter that returns the products that has to be displayed.I store those elements inside a variable.

[image]

`console.log` of this variable would be something like above.Now The returned set elements contains some of them with style `display="none"`. I want to select those with `display='none'` and display exactly two of the selected ones.

DOM structure of elements would be something like this

```
<body>
<ul class="products">
<li class="product" data-company="something" data-flavour="something"></li>
<li class="product" data-company="something" data-flavour="something"></li>
.
.
.
.

<li class="product" data-company="something" data-flavour="something"></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

How could i achieve this with jquery/Javascript?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of what you already tried with JS/jQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you storing the nodes in an array? That's what it looks like to me and if that is the case you can do something like this.

```
nodes.filter((node) => node.style.display === 'none')
```

or if you can't use arrow syntax:

```
nodes.filter(function (node) { return node.style.display === 'none' })
```

Comment: i would appreciate it , if you could show me some js fiddle or something :)

Comment: I'm not really sure what would go in such a fiddle, but if you use my example, `nodes` would just be the array containing all those DOM elements.

Comment: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined , am i missing something?

Comment: Well I think instead I've misunderstood your question, perhaps edit your question with some more information about what exactly is in the array.

Comment: Thanks matt, it's almost to what i wanted to do.I did a little tweaking to your code though.